# Inline getter and setter vs public variables

Tags: c++, oop

I saw that in some programs it is recommended the use of `public` variables instead of `get` and `set` functions for a better performance. I know that this is considered a bad practice. I also know that the compiler could make the `get` and `set` `inline`. Doesn't this mean that they behave like a variable with no performance fall-outs?

Comment: Assuming the getter and setter are trivial (something like `return x;` and `x = a;`) and are actually inlined, there's no performance difference.

Comment: You shouldn't bother about performance difference between those variants until profiler says it's a bottleneck. Usually contribute of member access for program performance is neglible.

Comment: If the getters/setters are equivalent to the public data members, that is to say, returning references to said data members, then each solution is as bad/good as the other. You are exposing the internals of your class either way (unless you have a clever way of returning references to objects that are not data members).

Comment: Just to say getters/setters aren't `oop`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler will most probably inline these functions ([see how](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion)), and there will be no function call overhead. I would avoid the getter, setter, and public member variables and instead think why these are used and provide a function to do that in that class. Most of the getter, setter, and public member variables can be removed this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can always expect compilers to inline trivial getters and setters and so you'll get identical performance.

There can be differences though, such as not being able to get a pointer or reference to the private member when using getters/setters if you're returning by value. Also, setters may have an extra copy or move operation.

Anyway, if you want public access then just use public variables. They are best practices.

Comment: Public member variables are not best practice. It is not even a good one, although unavoidable in some rare cases.

Comment: @lego That's why I said "if you want public access". Rarely one wants public access, except for cases like `std::pair` and PODs where it obviously makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

They should be the same performance-wise, *if* the compiler really choses to make them inline. The `inline` keyword is just a hint for the compiler, it must not strictly obey it, and vice-versa: it can make a function that is not marked with `inline` keyword, an inline one.

However, if for some reason the compiler will *not* make them inline, you will obviously lose some performance on the calls.